# Unchecking app on the protected network connections (under firewall advanced settings - windows defender properties) disabling firewall

Tags: security, firewall, windows-firewall, hamachi

So I'm trying to get Hamachi app to connect two PCs via RDP and the only way to do this without disabling firewall was by unchecking the app under protected network connections, but by doing so, I'm gettin windows pop ups that the firewall has been disabled though private and public networks under firewall are enabled. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Hamachi app wasn't connecting two PCs via RDP and the issue was with firewall - in specifically the settings under control panel - WD firewall - advanced settings - Windows defender firewall properties - protected network connections - there, you have to uncheck hamachi and do it for public and private profiles...

Comment: I also have set inbound and outbound rules to exclude hamachi app and also add the app to (allow apps to communicate through WD firewall) and that's about it, no more firewall settings were modified, but Windows keeps telling me that firewall is disabled through pop ups..